# harddisk hot-plug issue for Dell PowerEdge R720

Tags: raid, dell

Now I have 2 SAS harddisk plugged to R720 and formed a RAID 1 array.

What if I want to add more SATA harddisks to it without adding to the RAID, is it ok for me to add directly without reboot and directly connected to SATA controller?

Comment: What is "any handling"?

Comment: What I mean is the harddisks will be connected directly to SATA controller, but not RAID controller.

Comment: What SATA controller? The R720 has a backplane which is connected to either the H310 or the H710 RAID controller. There are no hot-swap bays connecting to SATA controller ports.

Comment: oh, it means that if I have a RAID array on R720, I cannot plug in harddisks and they cannot be detected when the server is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dell RAID controllers do support hot-plugging for SAS and SATA disks, so there would be no need to reboot the machine to be able to use the drives in array configurations.

But the disks will not be "passed through" as they are plugged into the backplane, so what you *would* need to do is run the [Storage Management](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/5.1/en/omss_ug/html/index.html) (or MegaCli if you prefer the command line) and create an array suiting your needs. After this is done, the newly created device will show up in your OS and be ready for use.